# Difference between python readline() and Java's Scanner class nextLine()

Tags: java, python

What is the difference between Python's readline() and Java's Scanner class method nextLine()?

nextLine() looks for the next line separator character which could be something other than "\n" as written here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Does the Python readline() method do the same? This is important because my file could have other line separators, but I need to look for specifically the new line character.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should test it by yourself.

I've tested it on the console using `f.readline()` and it reads until `\n`, even if I have a `\r` in the line.

```
>>> f.readline()
'This is a test\n'
>>> f.readline()
'Second line\rwith char\n'
>>> f.readline()
'Third line'
```

***NOTE:** Some weird things can happen if you simple print the read line on a python script. But if you use `repr(str)` you'll see all `\n` and `\r`.*

Comment: Thanks, but this does not consider the set of all possible line separators. There are unicode line separators which are not well known like the new line character.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are comparing apple to oranges. `Scanner` is **not** the Java equivalent of a python file object. `BufferedReader` *is* the equivalent, and in fact if you look at the [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method's documentation of `BufferedReader`:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed (`'\n'`), a carriage return (`'\r'`), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Python does [this](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) too:

> A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following
>   are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`,
>   the Windows convention `'\r\n'`, and the old Macintosh convention `'\r'`.
>   See PEP 278 and PEP 3116, as well as `str.splitlines()` for an
>   additional use.

---

AFAIK python does not provide a *public* equivalent of Java's `Scanner`. But there *is* an (undocumented) [`re.Scanner`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-April/035075.html) which could be used to achieve what you want.
You simply provide a "lexicon" when create an instance and then call the `scan` method.

Probably the easiest way of achieving what you want is to read the file in chunks, and split it using `re.split`.